# Disable "new email" notification (Wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress

I really searched lots of time, but I didn't find a working solution.

For example, this one should disable the "new pw" & "new email" notification, but it only disables the "new pw" notification.

```
add_filter( 'send_password_change_email', '__return_false' ); // working
add_filter( 'send_email_change_email', '__return_false' ); // not working
```

What's my fail? Is the order of these functions important?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, it's really the order! If you have any mail functions aso. in your `functions.php`, then you have to put this lines before it (work for me).